# Testcafe fixtureName and testname uniqueness

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We use testcafe for e2e tests and currently we are fixing flaky tests. During this we noticed that we use duplicated names for some fixtures and tests. Should we use unique names for fixtureName and testName or duplicated names are allowed?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate names are allowed but we don't recommend them as this is bad practice

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the documentation against it and the practice is allowed, but it's always best to be concise and unique: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402831/guides/basic-guides/organize-tests#fixtures

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).